# Calendar with TikZ; only print week days

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I'm trying to compose a TikZ calendar, but only want workdays printed. From the manual (I'm using v2.1):

> 57.1.2 Checking Dates
>
> ...
>
> - `workday` Passed by Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Thursdays, and Fridays.
> - `weekend` Passed Saturdays and Sundays.

I know I can pass formatting options or node shapes *on top of* dates based on these checks... but how can I completely omit them from being printed?

Or is a date check not the way to go about this?

I'm using `week list` since it's so convenient for a calendar format layout by just using `\calendar[dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-01-last]` vs. what I think I *might* have to do to get what I want, which is pass each weekly range for every month. This quadruples my lines of code and really reduces the re-usability of my document.

Is there a better way? I didn't see any examples of this in the manual.

---

If reproducible code is required, I'm looking for this but with no weekends printed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   [every calendar/.style={
       month label above left,
       month text={\textit{\%mt}},
       week list}]

   \calendar[dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-01-last] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `if(weekend) [<do something with this weekend>]` syntax. For example, you could set the weekend's color to `red`:

```
\calendar[dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-01-last] if(weekend) [red];
```

or, if you want it to disappear, to `white`. But this still prints out the actual node text. Or, even worse, you have white text on a colored background.

With the argument `coordinate` (short for `shape=coordinate`) you can transform the day node to a coordinate. A coordinate has no text.
Therefore there is not even a node text that is just hidden.

This will most likely be enough for most simple cases unless `every node` or `every day` (or another `if` later) will explicitly sets a shape. (If there's a `label` involved this will also still appear with a coordinate.)

The whole printing of the day node can be removed by setting [`day code`](https://tikz.dev/library-calender#tikz/day:code) to an empty value.

Of course, these can also be used via the `if` key which is appendable to an `every calendar` style.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\tikzset{
  no day/.style={shape=coordinate},
  no day'/.style={day code=}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  every calendar/.style={
    month label above left,
    month text={\textit{\%mt}},
    week list}]
 \calendar[dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-01-last] if(weekend) [no day];

\tikz[
  every calendar/.style={
    month label above left,
    month text={\textit{\%mt}},
    week list}]
 \calendar[dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-01-last] if(weekend) [no day'];
\end{document}
```

### Output

Note: The yellow boxes are a two-line selection that shows that there is no hidden text. Compare with the `[white]` version on the right.

[image: Output produces by the posted code] █ [image]

Comment: That's a nice shortcut.

Comment: Awesome! I had tried using `if(weekend)` and just passing no argument, hoping it would do nothing... but I think it defaults to doing "nothing" in the sense of "nothing other than what it was going to do anyway." I'll try this after lunch and accept if successful. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Hendy I'm glad I could help. Yes, the `[]` argument just gets passed to the internally `\node … {…}` command as `\node[]  … {…}`. It would just have no effect.

Comment: Just tried this and worked wonderfully. I added it to `every calendar/.style={..., if={(weekend) [shape=coordinate]}, ... }` so that I didn't have to add it to every instance. Fantastic and clever solution!