# Wrong positioning of month label tikz calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            [every calendar/.style={
                 month label above left,
                 month text={\textit{\%mt, \ \%y0}},
                 week list}]
         \calendar[dates=2013-07-01 to 2013-09-last];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Calendar}
    \label{fig:Calendar}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

I'm loading `\usepackage{tikz}` along with `\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}`

Any ideas why the label is so misplaced?

UPDATE:

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   

%Tikz Calendar
    \usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
Hola.

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            [every calendar/.style={
                 month label above left,
                 month text={\textit{\%mt, \ \%y0}},
                 week list}]
         \calendar[dates=2013-07-01 to 2013-09-last];
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Calendar}
    \label{fig:Calendar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are two curly braces `\end{tikzpicture}}`!

Comment: I'm sorry, typo while pasting.  Fixing the code

Comment: The problem is still there?

Comment: Yeap, unfortunately

Comment: @MarioS.E. please add the complete MWE.

Comment: I have the same problem here only using the `article` class and the `tikz` package with those libraries.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Please, remove all package that aren't necessary to reproduce the issue. Making an example really minimal sometimes helps in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: @egreg I would love to, but I'm not sure if any of them are causing an incompatibility problem, as I'm new to `tikz`

Comment: I just ran it with a few packages and still the same error.  Updating the MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason that is not obvious to me now, `week list` should be given before the `month label above left`. Probably the default spacing is for a different `list` and then week list comes afterwards making the spacing wrong.

Also you might use `/.append style` if you are not sure that you are not overwriting anything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}



\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                 every calendar/.append style={
                 week list,
                 month label above centered,
                 month text={\textit{\%mt, \ \%y0}},
}]
         \calendar[dates=2013-07-01 to 2013-09-last];
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it is not obvious to you, for me it would be unimaginable.

Comment: I second @Sigur.  It worked perfectly, but I have no idea why this happens

Comment: I actually took the code from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71039/27833

Comment: @MarioS.E., but there they use only one month.

Comment: @Sigur Yeap, but when you use more than one then you have this error that I showed in this question.  I'm really new to the `tikz` package, so I have no idea what I'm doing here

Comment: @MarioS.E. I think I know roughly why but it's not worth fixing it :) just swap the order.