# How to define a list of dates for tikz calendars

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, calendar, tikz-calendar

I am trying to pass a list of dates to a calendar using a pgf key, so that I can use it in different parts of the code.

Follow the PGF & TIKZ manual, I got it for `mybirthday` (see code below).
However, a similar idea does not work in `myholidays`. How can i fix it?
By the way, is there a better solution to define a "list" (or array, etc) of dates to achieve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\newcommand\myweekdayname[1]{\ifcase#1M\or T\or W\or T\or F\or S\or S\fi}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/mybirthday/.code={
    \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=1\relax
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=20\relax
            \pgfcalendarmatchestrue
        \fi\fi}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/myholidays/.code={
    \foreach \m / \d in {1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}{
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=\m\relax
            \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=\d\relax
                \pgfcalendarmatchestrue
            \fi\fi}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar[
        dates=2021-01-01 to 2021-01-last,
        day list downward, day yshift = 1em,
        day code={
            \ifdate{weekend, mybirthday, myholidays}{
                \node[shape=coordinate]{}; % trick (1)
                }{
                \node[anchor = east]{\tikzdaytext};
                \node[anchor = west, gray]{\myweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
                }},
        execute after day scope={
            \ifdate{weekend, mybirthday, myholidays}{\pgftransformyshift{1em}}{};
            \ifdate{Sunday}{\pgftransformyshift{-0.5em}}{} % week skip
            }       
        ];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*(1)* [Calendar with TikZ; only print week days](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71038/calendar-with-tikz-only-print-week-days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop body of `\foreach` is enclosed in a group, so changes with `\let`, `\def` and derived commands stay local, are forgotten at the end of the loop.

Since `\pgfcalendarmatchestrue` is defined as `\let \ifpgfcalendarmatches \iftrue`, it suffices to add `\global` in front:

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/myholidays/.code={
    \foreach \m / \d in {1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}{
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=\m\relax
            \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=\d\relax
                \global\pgfcalendarmatchestrue
            \fi\fi}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need your own calendar `.code`s there.

The `calendar` library already has `equals`, that way you can just do

```
my birthday/.style={equals=01-20}
```

For the holidays, you could just define

```
my holidays/.style={
  equals=1-4, equals=1-5, equals=1-6, equals=1-7, equals=1-8}
```

or even just

```
my holidays/.style={between=1-4 and 1-8}
```

But if you want to specify a comma seperated list of dates formatted
`<month>/<day>` you can use the `.list` handler
(it uses `\foreach` but without the grouping):

```
my holidays/.style={@my holidays/.list={1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}},
@my holidays/.style args={#1/#2}{equals={#1-#2}},
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\newcommand\myweekdayname[1]{\ifcase#1M\or T\or W\or T\or F\or S\or S\fi}
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{
  my birthday/.style={equals=01-20},
  % A
  % my holidays/.style={@my holidays/.list={1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8}},
  % @my holidays/.style args={#1/#2}{equals={#1-#2}},
  % B
  % my holidays/.style={
  %   equals=1-4, equals=1-5, equals=1-6, equals=1-7, equals=1-8},
  % C
  my holidays/.style={between=1-4 and 1-8},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar[
  dates=2021-01-01 to 2021-01-last,
  day list downward, day yshift = 1em,
  day code={
    \ifdate{weekend, my birthday, my holidays}{}{
      \node[anchor = east]{\tikzdaytext};
      \node[anchor = west, gray]{\myweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};}},
  execute after day scope={
    \ifdate{weekend, my birthday, my holidays}{\pgftransformyshift{1em}}{}
    \ifdate{Sunday}{\pgftransformyshift{-0.5em}}{} % week skip
  }];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]